# POST request for form with select box Laravel

Tags: laravel, post, request

I have a form with a select box. When the user selects and presses submit, that will get all the records for the selection in a new page.

I was using the GET request and it was working fine but because I couldn't get the proper pretty URL, for example I was getting `http://mywebsite.com/locations?=1` instead of `http://mywebsite.com/locations/slug`, users could change the number at the end and get more data, so I ended up using a POST request and it works fine.

The question is, is it ok to use a POST request in this case?

Comment: This is an improper question for SO. Please update it with code examples. Show us your form, route, and controller code. This isn't a place to just ask "Is this OK" questions.

Comment: Ok i will update thw question soon. I know it was a litle vague but sometimes it is difficult to formulate the question for somebody relative new to this.

Comment: im guessing you dont have correct method tags in the form. like ```<form method="POST"></form>```